# Display vector struct within vector struct

Tags: c++, function, vector, struct, iterator

I'm a true beginner and this is really complicated for me. I've been looking for an answer but i have not been able to find it here or if i have seen it.. it seems to be complicated for me.

Here is what I'm trying to do:

I have this headers

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
```

And i have this structs

```
struct stFecha {
    int dia;
    int mes;
    int ano;
};

struct stPersona {
    string cedula;
    string nombre;
    string apellido;
    stFecha fechaNacimiento;
    char estado;
};

struct stCuentaBancaria{
    string numeroCuenta;
    string nombreOficialBancario;
    double totalDebito;
    double totalCredito;
    vector<stPersona> clientesCuenta;
    char estado;
```

i declared these vectors that are the ones i will be working with

```
vector<stPersona> clientes;
vector<stCuentaBancaria> cuentas;
```

And this is the code i'm using to iterate through the structs and check if a person already exists in the record.

```
for( vector<stPersona>::iterator it = clientes.begin();  !existe && it != clientes.end(); ++it )
{
    existe = cedula.compare( (*it).cedula ) == 0 ;
    if ( existe )
    {
        cout << "NOMBRE :"   << (*it).nombre   << '\n' 
             << "APELLIDO :" << (*it).apellido << '\n' 
             << "CEDULA :" << (*it).cedula << '\n'
             << "FECHA DE NACIMIENTO DD/MM/AAAA:\n"
             << "DIA: " << (*it).fechaNacimiento.dia << '\n'
             << "MES: " << (*it).fechaNacimiento.mes << '\n'
             << "A\xA5O: " << (*it).fechaNacimiento.ano << '\n'
             << "ESTADO: "<< (*it).estado << '\n';
    }
```

I can see that even though `fechaNacimiento`is a struct i can accesso the data in this struct easily because it is not a vector.

In the other hand before i add a new account to the vector `cuentas` i need to check if the ID or `cedula` is registered into my customer's `clientes` data. so I'm using this following code to find if the record exists.

```
stCuentaBancaria cuenta;
cout << "CEDULA DEL CLIENTE: ";
cin >> cedula;

bool existe = false;

for ( vector<stPersona>::iterator it = clientes.begin(); !existe && it != clientes.end(); ++it )
{
existe = cedula.compare( (*it).cedula ) == 0;
if ( existe )
{
    cuenta.clientesCuenta.push_back((*it));                             
}
```

From my perspective it is supposed to copy the record found in `clientes` which is type `stPersona`to `clientesCuenta` which is as well a struct `stPersona` within the struct `stCuentas` which stands for the banking accounts. so far i get no errors.

But here is where i dont see how to get things working for me...

I wish to consult the records and when it finds the desired record to display the data within the record but when i did, as before with the iterator of the customers `clientes`, this one doesnt work. It contains a vector inside it gives me an error

```
cout<<"\n\n2.CONSULTA POR CUENTA\n";
string cuenta;
cout << "INTRODUCIR CUENTA A CONSULTAR .:";
cin  >> cuenta;

bool existe = false;


for( vector<stCuentaBancaria>::iterator it = cuentas.begin();  !existe && it != cuentas.end(); ++it )
                    {
existe = cuenta.compare( (*it).numeroCuenta ) == 0 ;
if ( existe )
{
    cout << "NUMERO DE CUENTA :"   << (*it).numeroCuenta   << '\n' 
         << "NOMBRE OFICIAL DE CUENTA :" << (*it).nombreOficialBancario << '\n' 
         << "TOTAL DEBITO : " << (*it).totalDebito << '\n'
         << "TOTAL CREDITO: " << (*it).totalCredito << '\n'
         << "ESTADO: "<< (*it).estado << '\n'
         << "TUTORIALES DE CUENTA: " << (*it).clientesCuenta << '\n'; 
}
```

I tried using `(*it).clientesCuenta`but this is the vector struct `stPersonas`within the vector `cuentas` previously declarated.

I dont know how do i get access to display this data nor how to get access to modify it in the future if i find it.

Please help.

**additional note**: I'm accessing this data through functions

```
int manejoCuentas(vector<stCuentaBancaria> &cuentas,vector<stPersona> &clientes, int &opcionMenu)
```

And this is how i send the data from the main function

```
manejoCuentas(cuentas, clientes, opcion);
```

My english is not very good thanks for reading this and any help would be more than welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Defining following three overloading of the operator `<<`, we can simplify the code that outputs the members of your PODs.
Since `stFecha`, `stPersona` and `stCuentaBancaria` are all POD types and their members are all public, we do not need to define friend functions on them:

```
#include <ostream>

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o, const stFecha& fecha)
{
    o << "DIA   : " << fecha.dia  << '\n';
    o << "MES   : " << fecha.mes  << '\n';
    o << "A\\xA5O: " << fecha.ano;

    return o;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o, const stPersona& persona)
{
    o << "NOMBRE   : " << persona.nombre   << '\n';
    o << "APELLIDO : " << persona.apellido << '\n';
    o << "CEDULA   : " << persona.cedula   << '\n';

    o << "FECHA DE NACIMIENTO DD/MM/AAAA:\n";
    o << persona.fechaNacimiento << '\n';

    o << "ESTADO   : " << persona.estado;

    return o;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o, const stCuentaBancaria& bancaria)
{
    o << "NUMERO DE CUENTA         : " << bancaria.numeroCuenta          << '\n';
    o << "NOMBRE OFICIAL DE CUENTA : " << bancaria.nombreOficialBancario << '\n';
    o << "TOTAL DEBITO             : " <<bancaria.totalDebito            << '\n';
    o << "TOTAL CREDITO            : " << bancaria.totalCredito          << "\n\n";

    o << "TUTORIALES DE CUENTA\n"; 
    for(const auto& ceunta_i : bancaria.clientesCuenta){
        o << ceunta_i << "\n\n";
    }

    o << "ESTADO: "<< bancaria.estado;

    return o;
}
```

Then you can output the data of each element of `std::vector<stCuentaBancaria> cuentas` to `std::cout` or some other output stream with just a one liner as follows.

[**DEMO**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/NTk46hntsPhrRLJZ)

```
std::cout << *it << std::endl;
```

Comment: wow this definitely looks a lot better than what i'm trying to do... i guess i have a lot of study to do...a friend of mine gave me some hints and i broke my brain and i managed to accomplished what i wanted accessing through it with a second iterator that moves in whenever there is a struct inside of the struct... I'll read into overloading the operator because the example you provided me is a lot cleaner than what i already have. Thank you very much.

Comment: @MiguelArturoSanchezCuello thx. It's my pleasure. If this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this : ) .

Comment: sorry for the delay i was very busy with some college tests... i managed to get the way around with what i wanted to do and it worked but i'm still very interested in learning how to do what you showed me in the code :-) I do appreciate taking the help me out :-)

Answer (score 0):

Override the function to output a vector of stCuentaBancaria

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const vector &cuentas) 
for(int i=0; i< cuentas.size(); i++){
os << "TUTORIALES DE CUENTA: " << i << ' ' << cuentas[i] << '\n';
}
return *os;
}